# mac mini 2014 monitor wake up issue

Tags: mac, monitor, wakeup

My 2014 ubuntufied macmini wakes up from sleep but the monitor doesnt. i guess the mini is missing out sending a signal to it. i had the same issue in osx but after the latest update that went away (So, it looks like a software issue to me).

Let me know if there is a fix. makes earth a little more greener(aka saves some power)